# What's the canonical way to check URL direction in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, routes

I'm doing TDD in my Ruby on Rails development. I have code that looks like this:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe "Schedule routing" do

  it "by default should redirect /schedule to 'schedule/dateview'" do
    visit("/schedule")
    current_path.should == "/schedule/dateview"                                                                                      
  end

end
```

Is this there a more succinct way to check for routing?

EDIT: Adding my routes.rb for more context:

```
 get "schedule/dateview", to: "events#dateview"
 get "schedule/courseview", to: "events#courseview"
 match "/schedule" => redirect("/schedule/dateview"), via: :get
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a controller spec something like this should work

```
it "by default should redirect /schedule to schedule/dateview'" do
  visit schedule_path
  response.should redirect_to schedule_dateview_path
end
```

Comment: I got this response: `Failure/Error: response.should redirect_to schedule_dateview_path ArgumentError: @request must be an ActionDispatch::Request` Does it have to do with the fact that `/schedule` doesn't map to a "real" request object (i.e. GET/POST)?

Comment: It could be, you could run `rake routes` and see what the route name of that route is. If it's a custom action you created Rails might not have created a good path name for you OR it's different from what I guessed it might be.